# input during for-loop in comprension

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
data=[]
for i in range(int(input())):
    name=input()
    point=float(input())
    data.append([name,point])
```

how i can convert this code to comprehension or is there any other way to reduce runtime.

for comprehension i tried this code below:

```
data=[[input() float(input())] for i in range(int(input()))]
```

i dont know is there  any special ways to do list opearations and inputs during for-loop in comprensions.
As i know for statements, they should be mentioned after loop but operations for list before loop. But for my version it gives syntax error.

Comment: you need `[input(), float(input())]` , i.e. you need a comma to separate the items in your list literals. Honestly, you should probably just stick to your for-loop. It is much more readable.

Comment: List comprehension is not necessarily faster [Benefits of Using List Comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#benefits-of-using-list-comprehensions)

Comment: From a time complexity standpoint. This is not a bad loop. The longest part of this loop will honestly be the manual input

Answer (score 0):

> how i can convert this code to comprehension or is there any other way to reduce runtime.

Do the items of your outer list need to be more lists? Why not make a list of tuples? Anyways your code gave you a syntax error because you forgot to include a comma.

```
data = [(input(), float(input())) for i in range(int(input()))]
```

I'm also not sure why you are trying to find speed improvements on code that takes user input. No human is every going to provide input fast enough to notice any performance increase from one solution to another. Do you have another program providing input automatically through stdin or something?